# Change the order of switching tkinter.spinbox "values"

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to change the order of switching values in Spinbox widget, in case, when "values" parametr is set. This could be similar like a "increment=-1", when using "from_" and "to" paramentrs. I want, just the opposite, when i'm clicking "downbutton" - index of values is increaseing...

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
values = ['1.Python','2.Ruby','3.PHP','4.Perl','5.JavaScript']
spin_box = Spinbox(root,
                   textvariable=var,
                   values=values,
                   wrap=True,
                   command=lambda: print(var.get()),
                   width=12)
spin_box.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse your list, and initialize the value with the last item in the reversed list. It doesn't change the index of the selected item per se, but it makes the down arrow move through the list in the opposite way.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
values = ['1.Python','2.Ruby','3.PHP','4.Perl','5.JavaScript']
values = values[::-1]
var = StringVar()
spin_box = Spinbox(root,
                   textvariable=var,
                   values=values,
                   wrap=True,
                   command=lambda: print(var.get()),
                   width=12)
var.set(values[-1])
spin_box.pack(padx=50, pady=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks, this is so simple, and exactly what i needed... Now i think, that i was stuck, because i'm stupid...

Comment: instead of `values[::-1]` use `reversed(values)`

Comment: @DCPY: `reversed` returns a generator.  The spinbox needs an actual list. Of course, I could use a list comprehension to convert the results to an actual list, but slicing seemed a bit easier.

Comment: small addition, i ran into a problem when i was using reverse only, and fixed it, at this way:
  `values.reverse();
   values = values[-1:] + values[:-1];
   var.set(values[0])`